# MSSQL parameter limit error

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm trying to write a function to insert data into a MSSQL dB, however cannot overcome this error:

> Tried to bind parameter number 65536.  SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters.

No matter what I try I get this error back and can find no help or hint of a clue as to how to solve the problem.

My code currently looks like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO SMARTCM . dbo . CITATIONLOOKUP_PAYMENT     (username, citation_num, payment_date)
          VALUES (':username', ':citation_num', ':payment_date')";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindParam(':citation_num', $citation_num, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindParam(':payment_date', $date, PDO::PARAM_INT);

  $user = '';
  $citation_num = '';
  $date = '';

  $stmt->execute();
```

Obviously this should insert blank data into the dB, which I've setup just to test what the heck is going on, but even with zero data I'm getting the maximum limit error.

Comment: Remove the quotes from the parameters `VALUES (:username, :citation_num, :payment_date)";` You shouldn't use them here as PDO takes care of it for you.

Comment: Also `SMARTCM . dbo . CITATIONLOOKUP_PAYMENT`  something looks fishy there. Please check it's correct

Comment: No problem, I have added my answer as an answer (not as an comment). @zhwatts

Comment: Dont change you question to include answers given. It makes the answer look incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `:user` in the `bindParam` and `:username` in the `$sql`. Change them, so they are the same.

Comment: wow-- you caught it! Thanks for proof reading me when I've been pulling my hair out over this!!